# How is it possible to pass two positional arguments to unittest.patch when it only accepts one?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm writing tests for a [Home Assistant](https://github.com/home-assistant/core) integration using tests from another integration as an example. There is a [method](https://github.com/home-assistant/core/blob/963b5db763842d36b107b9ed8509366ddd0925cc/tests/components/ring/common.py#L10) that is called from each test function that is some how calling `patch` with two positional arguments:

```
async def setup_platform(hass, platform):
    """Set up the ring platform and prerequisites."""
    MockConfigEntry(domain=DOMAIN, data={"username": "foo", "token": {}}).add_to_hass(
        hass
    )
    with patch("homeassistant.components.ring.PLATFORMS", [platform]):
        assert await async_setup_component(hass, DOMAIN, {})
    await hass.async_block_till_done()
```

The first positional argument `"homeassistant.components.ring.PLATFORMS"` is obviously a string but is pointing to the constant `PLATFORMS` which is a tuple `("binary_sensor", "light", "sensor", "switch", "camera")`. The second positional argument `platform` is passed in `setup_platform` as a string that will be either `"binary_sensor"`, `"light"`, `"sensor"`, `"switch"` or `"camera"` (same items as the `PLATFORMS` tuple), but gets passed into `patch` as a dictionary with one string item.

My understanding of what's happening is this results in only the `platform` passed being patched.

What I can't figure out is how two positional arguments can be passed into `patch` when it only accepts [one positional argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). Are the two positional arguments some how being combined into one before `patch` is called?

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch path accepts more than one argument. 

The second position argument to patch is new, the third is spec, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the other arguments are just getting default values, but they are still positional arguments.

Comment: Well, that explains that, lol. Thanks. I knew that at one point but some how convinced myself keyword arguments required a key. So in this case, a list with one string item `[platform]` is being passed as the `new` key argument in unittest.patch:

`unittest.mock.patch(target, new=DEFAULT, spec=None, create=False, spec_set=None, autospec=None, new_callable=None, **kwargs)`

I suppose now i just need to figure out how a list works with the `new` keyword argument in unittest.patch.